# Template function is not a member of a namespace

Tags: c++, templates

I have a header file, `RandFunctions.hpp` which contains a template function,

```
#ifndef _RANDFUNCTIONS_HPP_
#define _RANDFUNCTIONS_HPP_
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

namespace surena
{
  namespace common
  {

template<typename RealT> inline
RealT
RealRandom()
{
  return rand()/(RealT(RAND_MAX)+1);
}  

  };
};
#endif
```

and another header file, `Search.hpp` which includes `RandFunctions.hpp`,

```
#ifndef _SEARCH_HPP_
#define _SEARCH_HPP_

#include "RandFunctions.hpp"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

namespace surena
{
  namespace search
  {

template<typename RealT>
class CTest
{
  public:
    CTest() {srand((unsigned)(time(0)));}

    RealT
    GenRand(){ return common::RealRandom(); }
};

  };
};
#endif
```

when I include `Search.hpp` in a `cpp` file, for example,

```
#include "Search.hpp"

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  CTest<float> test;
  return(0);
}
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
‘RealRandom’ is not a member of ‘surena::common’
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Use a compiler [with better diagnostic messages](http://ideone.com/ENZpBQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `RealRandom` is a template function with no parameters, you need to provide a template argument:

```
GenRand(){ return common::RealRandom<RealT>(); }
                                    ^^^^^^^
```

Also in your main you'd have to qualify your `test` variable with the proper namespaces:

```
surena::search::CTest<float> test;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Now, I get two additional errors: `expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token` and `expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token`